# Enumerate all certificates in Mac Keychain and compare creation/expiry dates

Tags: macos, keychain, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to write a script that will list all installed certificates in the keychain and compare them to the creation/expiration dates of certificates from the Apple dev portal.

I've looked at the documentation for `security` ( https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html ) and `openssl`, but I can't seem to pass a cert from one to the other.

The alternative is to use the `Security.framework` directly, but I don't see any obvious method for dumping the creation/expiry dates for certificates.

Any guidance?

Comment: Check the source code for *Keychain Dumper*. You can usually find it around iOS jailbreak utilities used by pentesters.

Comment: The source code seems to do the same as `security find-certificate`, where it dumps the the values you can see on the command line. No dates.

Answer (score 8):

At the command line, I think you could do `security find-certificate -a -p` and then split up the returned PEM-encoded certificates to feed them to `openssl x509 -inform PEM ....` one by one.

In code, you can enumerate certificates using `SecItemCopyMatching` with `kSecClass`=`kSecClassCertificate` and `kSecMatchLimit`=`kSecMatchLimitAll`. You might be able to get the certificate's expiration date using `SecCertificateCopyValues()`, but if not, you could get the certificate itself (as a DER-encoded blob) using `SecCertificateCopyData()` and pipe it to `openssl x509 -inform DER ....`.